# How to have one subscribe for many timers?

Tags: rxjs

I have array of milliseconds:  `[3 * 1000, 30 * 1000, 10 * 1000]`.

When the millisecond event is ready then I log into the console:

```
milliseconds.forEach(m => {

  timer(m).subscribe(r => { console.log('notification!!'); });
});
```

Is there a way to make one subscribe for get the events in the right time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
merge(milliseconds.map(t => timer(t))
.subscribe(r => { console.log('notification!!');
```

Consider that the `merge` used here is the `merge` function imported from `rxjs` and not the `merge` operator imported from `rxjs/operators`